# Match pattern 1 and/or pattern 2

Tags: python, regex

I have multiple file names that are either a movie title or an episode in a TV show. For the movie titles I want to match the year the movie came out, and for the episode I want to match the season and episode number in the format `S00E00`. However, I can't known that the string contains either or, sometimes it can contain both the season and episode **and** the year. I also don't known what comes first in the string, the year or the season and episode.

I tried with the following pattern: `(\d{4})|S(\d\d)E(\d\d)`, however that only returns a match for the one that came first. For the string `2012.S01E02`, it returns `2012`, and for the string `S01E02.2012` it returns `S01E02`. The rest of the capture groups is `None` (I'm using Python 3.5).

I have a solution which uses two separate matches, if-statements and generally looks ugly. Is there's a way to have one regex pattern that returns a list (or tuple) witch contains `(year, season, episode)`, regardless of what comes first in the string?

Comment: if you use `re.findall` it should find every match.  so `2012.S01E02` would give you `[('2012', '', ''), ('', '01', '02')]`

Comment: That is a lot more useful than what I have, thanks. I can more easily work with that result.

Comment: Could you please post some input lines and the output you want, as is the case with typical regex questions?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following regular expression:

```
.*?(\d{4}).*?(S\d{2}E\d{2}).*?|.*?(S\d{2}E\d{2}).*?(\d{4}).*?|.*?(S\d{2}E\d{2}).*?|.*?(\d{4}).*?
```

1. `.*?(\d{4}).*?(S(\d\d)E(\d\d)).*?`: This will first match the combination of the year and episode number in this order.
2. `.*?(S(\d\d)E(\d\d)).*?(\d{4}).*?`: This will match the reverse order
3. `.*?(S(\d\d)E(\d\d)).*?`: This will match the episode number
4. `.*?(\d{4}).*?`: This will match the year.

If you execute the regular expression in this order, you will always get both the year and the episode number.

```js
var regex = /.*?(\d{4}).*?(S\d{2}E\d{2}).*?|.*?(S\d{2}E\d{2}).*?(\d{4}).*?|.*?(S\d{2}E\d{2}).*?|.*?(\d{4}).*?/;

var matches = "test|S02E12|2012_test".match(regex);
matches = matches.filter(function(item) {
  return item !== undefined;
}).splice(1).sort();

console.log(matches);
```